# Quickbooks API: How to generate purchase order against the orders placed by guest in quickbooks using api?

Tags: api, quickbooks-online, opencart-3, purchase-order

I have developed eCommerce website with OpenCart framework where when customer places order purchase order should be created in QuickBooks.

I have referred this documentation https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/purchaseorder

The api to create a purchase order accepts following json input
{
  "PurchaseOrder": {
    "DocNumber": "1005", 
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "APAccountRef": {
      "name": "Accounts Payable (A/P)", 
      "value": "33"
    }, 
    "CurrencyRef": {
      "name": "United States Dollar", 
      "value": "USD"
    }, 
    "TxnDate": "2015-07-28", 
    "TotalAmt": 25.0, 
    "ShipAddr": {
      "Line4": "Half Moon Bay, CA  94213", 
      "Line3": "65 Ocean Dr.", 
      "Id": "121", 
      "Line1": "Grace Pariente", 
      "Line2": "Cool Cars"
    }, 
    "VendorAddr": {
      "Line4": "Middlefield, CA  94303", 
      "Line3": "42 Main St.", 
      "Id": "120", 
      "Line1": "Geoff Hicks", 
      "Line2": "Hicks Hardware"
    }, 
    "POStatus": "Open", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "VendorRef": {
      "name": "Hicks Hardware", 
      "value": "41"
    }, 
    "Line": [
      {
        "DetailType": "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail", 
        "Amount": 25.0, 
        "Id": "1", 
        "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail": {
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Garden Supplies", 
            "value": "38"
          }, 
          "CustomerRef": {
            "name": "Cool Cars", 
            "value": "3"
          }, 
          "Qty": 1, 
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          }, 
          "BillableStatus": "NotBillable", 
          "UnitPrice": 25
        }
      }
    ], 
    "CustomField": [
      {
        "DefinitionId": "1", 
        "Type": "StringType", 
        "Name": "Crew #"
      }, 
      {
        "DefinitionId": "2", 
        "Type": "StringType", 
        "Name": "Sales Rep"
      }
    ], 
    "Id": "257", 
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2015-07-28T16:01:47-07:00", 
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2015-07-28T16:01:47-07:00"
    }
  }, 
  "time": "2015-07-28T16:04:49.874-07:00"
}

My website has a guest checkout so I need to know how to generate purchase order for guests as the above json format expects customer id to be sent. Since it is guest who is placing order I do not have customer id to pass for the api

Comment: I think even guests have a customer ID. If not, use email address - it's often a good unique identifier.

Comment: I tried passing guest name without customer id. It generate purchase order with blank customer name.
I need to know whether there is a way to guest details directly.